# How to undo the scroll of a html slider button?

Tags: html, button, scroll, slider

My problem is that when I press my "slider__navlink" buttons. They scroll to the div of the desired slide. I would like to be able to cancel this scroll or make a scroll to the level of the title above while displaying the correct slide.

```
<h1 class="competences" id="competences">Mes compétences</h1><hr class="hrtitre">

<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div id="slides__1" class="slide">
        <h1>Front-end</h1>
        <div class="language">
          <div class="html">
            <img src="img/html-5v.png" alt="">
            <div class="progressbar-wrapper">
              <div title="downloaded" class="progressbar mp4"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="css">
            <img src="img/css-3.png" alt="">
            <div class="progressbar-wrapper">
              <div title="downloaded" class="progressbar mp4"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="slides__2" class="slide">
        <span class="slide__text">2</span>
      </div>
      <div id="slides__3" class="slide">
        <span class="slide__text">3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__nav">
      <a class="slider__navlink" href="#slides__1"></a>
      <a class="slider__navlink" href="#slides__2"></a>
      <a class="slider__navlink" href="#slides__3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try some js script but it interfere with the button and his first functionnality

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly.

You can use scroll-behavior: smooth

And this CSS code:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

:target:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -100px 0 0;
}
```